# Jquery DataTable not displaying

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm attempting to use jquery datatables to format my data in a much more readable way, but when I attempt to use it as described in the [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/) page, it never actually displays the data in the datatables formatting.  (in this case I'm adding the links stated on that page to the view that I would like to have the datatable, I understand that I would need to set it up differently in order to have it applicationwide, but for now I'm just trying to test using it)
Code is below, what mistake am I making here:

```
@model APTII_MVC.ViewModel.AssignViewModel

<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#table_id').dataTable();
    });
</script>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AssignList";
}

<h2>AssignList</h2>

<table id="table_id" 

class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Project ID
            </th>
            <th>
                Employer ID
            </th>
            <th>
                Employer Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Client Type
            </th>
            <th>
                Service Start Date
            </th>
            <th>
                Project Type
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.ProjectsLists )
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Project_ID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Employer_ID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.EmployerRef)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.APT_ClientTypes.Description)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ServiceStartDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.APT_ProjectTypes.Description)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: have a look : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1114208/Beginners-Guide-for-Creating-GridView-in-ASP-NET-M

Comment: The code you have shown does not have `jquery-{version}.js` loaded. Check your browser console for errors

Comment: try settimeout(function(){  $('#table_id').dataTable();}, 500) in your ready function'